# convert string containing a hex value into a char byte in c

Tags: c++, c, string

Hey guys I am working with a software that needs to check for a char byte lets say like this:

```
char id = 0xa2;
```

As we all know that is a char byte in hex, what I need is a way to read from a txt file that same hex number, and compare it with id.
As you may notice when you read from a file what you have is a char pointer containing the string let's say 0xa2 I need a way that I could compare the two values to check if it is the same ID obviously I know that one of the two values have to be converted to match the other, I just dont know how to do it and I have tried several methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is to convert the char to a string. E,g,

```
char idStr[5];
sprintf(idStr, "0x%02x", (unsigned char)id);
```

The compare idStr with the string read from the file.

Case might be an issue, obviously 0xA2 and 0xa2 should compare equal.

Comment: thanks @jhon you gave a nice idea I did it that way then I compare the two strings with a little function I created and pum working fine good stuff

Answer (score 3):

You could use a modification of the following answers:

- [How to turn a hex string into an unsigned char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221170/how-to-turn-a-hex-string-into-an-unsigned-char-array)
- [Hex to char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557400/hex-to-char-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following solution. Instead of a file stream I am using a string stream.

```
    std::istringstream is( "0xa2" );

    char id = '\xa2';

    int x;

    is >> std::hex >> x;

    if ( id == static_cast<char>( x ) ) std::cout << "They are equal each other" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks bro but I am using plain C cannot c++