# Coverting a std::string into an array of bytes

Tags: c++

So I have a string of bytes, for example

```
std::string bytes = "55DEBEFF4A";
```

I'd like to read them into an unsigned char array.

```
unsigned char* myArray = new unsigned char[len];
```

Whats the best way to do it? I'd like to access it with myArray[0] being 0x55
myArray[1] being 0xDE

Thanks!

Comment: What's a string of bytes?

Comment: Did you mean: `std::string bytes = "\x55\xDE\xBE\xFF\x4A";` ?

Comment: Regardless a `std::string` contains a char array you can just do `bytes.data()` to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answers of the following questions, I think they will help you find your way to the answer of your question:

- [Hex to char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557400/hex-to-char-array-in-c)
- [How to turn a hex string into an unsigned char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221170/how-to-turn-a-hex-string-into-an-unsigned-char-array)

Answer (score 1):

Thos aren't bytes. They're characters. To translate the first two characters into a value, you need something like this:

```
int value = ((bytes[0] - '0') << 8) + bytes[1] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to use hexadecimal, you need to write your number `0x55DEBEFF4A`. 
You cannot assign an integer to a string. I think your best solution is to directly create your array like this:

```
unsigned char myArray[] = { 0x55, 0xDE, 0xBE, 0xFF, 0x4A };
```

**EDIT:** As Galik said, you can also do:

```
std::string bytes = "\x55\xDE\xBE\xFF\x4A";
unsigned char myArray[] = bytes.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have text reading "55DEBEFF4A". Let's assume that's ASCII because it 's a lot harder and a lot rarer than the alternatives. To turn this into bytes, you're going to have to work through the characters and convert the suckers character by character.

Here are a couple borderline horrible ways to do the translation that hopefully will suggest better ways to do it.

An ugly map-based approach:

```
std::map<char, int> cnv
{
    {'0',  0},
    {'1',  1},
    {'2',  2},
    {'3',  3},
    {'4',  4},
    {'5',  5},
    {'6',  6},
    {'7',  7},
    {'8',  8},
    {'9',  9},
    {'a', 10},
    {'b', 11},
    {'c', 12},
    {'d', 13},
    {'e', 14},
    {'f', 15},
    {'A', 10},
    {'B', 11},
    {'C', 12},
    {'D', 13},
    {'E', 14},
    {'F', 15}
};
std::vector<uint8_t> binarray(const std::string & in)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> out;
    bool newnum = true;
    size_t loc = 0;
    for (char val: in)
    {
        if (newnum)
        {
            out.push_back(cnv[val]);
            newnum = false;
        }
        else
        {
            out [loc] <<= 4;
            out [loc] +=cnv[val];
            ++loc;
            newnum = true;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

And here's one taking advantage of iostreams:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> binarray2(const std::string & in)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> out;
    std::stringstream cnv;
    bool newnum = true;

    for (char ch:in)
    {
        cnv << ch;
        if (newnum)
        {
            newnum = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cnv <<  ' ';
            newnum = true;
        }
    }

    int val;
    cnv >> std::hex;
    while (cnv >> val)
    {
        out.push_back(val);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Note they both return `std::vector`. You can pass around the vector easily, it contains all the sizing information you need, and it manages its own memory. You can use `std::vector::data` to get the byte array you need. All you have to do is keep the vector around until you aye done with the byte array or it will free the array out from underneath you.