# convert binascii.unhexlify function in C

Tags: python, c, sockets, tcp

**How to send binascii.unhexlify data in C**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #OPENS NEW SOCKET
inputHex = binascii.unhexlify("1000020a4767b525156d5de2957833a5")
s.connect((ip,port))#SOCKET CONNECTION
s.send(inputHex)
```

my code in c

```
data_len = util_strlen(user_payload);
sendto(rfd, pkt, sizeof (struct iphdr) + sizeof (struct tcphdr) + data_len, MSG_NOSIGNAL, (struct sockaddr *)&targs[i].sock_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What specifically is your question? Is it just about converting the hex string into raw data for sending? Is it about sending data in general?

Comment: For converting the hex string, see [Hex to char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557400/hex-to-char-array-in-c)

Comment: @Gerhardh yes im about to send hex data to socket . i can't get it work it always send data as string

Comment: Did you try to use the solution from the linked question? Please edit your question to include the attempt to convert your string. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details what you should provide.