# Storing integer in the array of char

Tags: c, arrays, types

I've been reading this thread [Store an int in a char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522994/store-an-int-in-a-char-array)

And I need to store the int in the array of chars.

So I read the previous thread and I tried to make my own demo. But it's not working, trying to figure out why not for a long time. Maybe you could give me some clue or ideas please?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char buffer[4];
    int y = 2200;
    buffer[0] = (y >> 0) & 0xff;
    buffer[1] = (y >> 8) & 0xff;
    buffer[2] = (y >> 16) & 0xff;
    buffer[3] = (y >> 24) & 0xff;

    int x = buffer[0];

    printf("%i = %i\n", y, x);
}
```

Output

```
gcc tmp.c && ./a.out
2200 = -104
```

Comment: This doesn't address your question directly, but be aware of the assumption you are making about the size of `int` on your system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int x = buffer[0];
```

Copies the value of the *`char`* at `buffer[0]`, implicitly converted to an int, into `x`.  It does not  interpret the first `sizeof int` bytes starting at `buffer` as an `int`, which is what you want (think of the evil ways that this behavior would subtly break in common scenarios, i.e., `char c = 10; int x = c`.  Oops!).

Realize that `buffer[n]` doesn't return a memory address, it returns a `char`.  To interpret `sizeof int` elements as one whole `int` just cast `buffer` to an `int*` first:

```
int x = *((int*)buffer);
```

And for an offset `n` (measured in `int`s, not `char`s):

```
int x = *((int*)buffer + n);
```

---

Also note that your code assumes `sizeof int == 4`, which is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

`x = buffer[0]` does not do what you wish. Try `memcpy(&x,buffer,sizeof(x))`. (You'll need to add `#include <string.h>`.)