# load/store between 8-bit and 32-bit values

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Store an int in a char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522994/store-an-int-in-a-char-array)

i want to load 4 8-bit unsigned char to 32-bit integer. And store 32 bit integer to unsigned char pointer. How is this possible?Example usage below;

```
int 32bitint1= 0xff000000 | (uchar1<<16) | (uchar2<<8) | uchar3;
int 32bitint2= 0xff000000 | (uchar4<<16) | (uchar5<<8) | uchar6;
//then this 32-bit integer to uchar pointer;
ucharpointer[0] = 32bitint1;
ucharpointer[4] = 32bitint2;//is this possible?or how
```

Comment: Why not assign the chars to the char arrays directly where you want them?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it?

Comment: What compiler doesn't have issues with a variable name like `32bitint1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Store**: (store 4 chars into an unsigned int)

```
int store(uint32_t * reg, unsigned char c[4])
{
    *reg = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            *reg = (*reg<<8) | c[i];
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**Load**: (load 4 chars from an unsigned int)

```
int load(uint32_t * reg, unsigned char c[4])
{
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            c[i] = *reg;
            *reg = *reg>>8;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**Usage example**:

```
int main ()
{
    unsigned char c[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    uint32_t reg;

    printf("%c",c[0]);  //it prints 'a'
    store(&reg,c);   

    c[0] = 'e';
    printf("%c",c[0]);  //it prints 'e'

    load(&reg,c);     //load
    printf("%c",c[0]);  //it prints 'a' again

    return 0;
}
```

**If you don't want to reload them into a char array, but to access them by a char pointer, then here's an example**:

```
int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unsigned char c[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    uint32_t reg;
    store(&reg,c);

    unsigned char *cpointer = (unsigned char *) &reg;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",cpointer[i]);  //access the 4 chars by a char pointer
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that the you will get an output 'dcba' in this way, as the memory address are made in the reverse order.

Comment: There is not guarantee that unsigned int == 4 bytes

Comment: @DavidRF Thank you! I have replaced them with `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bytes are read big endian, store each 4 byte forming 32 byte as

```
uint32_t bit_32 = ((uint32_t)uchar[0] << 24) |  ((uint32_t)uchar[1] << 16) | ((uint32_t)uchar[2] << 8) | ((uint32_t)uchar[3])
```

store 32 bit integer to unsigned char pointer as,

```
unsigned char *ptr = &bit_32;
```

Comment: If you shift an 8 bit variable more then 7 times to the left it will be 0. your uchar variables should be 32 bit for this to work. You could add a cast infront of each one of them e.g. `(uint32_t)uchar[0] << 24` otherwise your example returns only zero.

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev Before the shift, the integer promotions are performed. So the width is at least 16 bits. But, even with 32-bit `int`s (and 8-bit `char`s), `uchar[0] << 24` can overflow, which would be undefined behaviour. Thus one should use `uint32_t`, and one _needs_ the cast on `uchar[0]` [unless `int` is more than 32 bits wide].

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev my mistake. calling them all to `int`.