# How do I parse a char array as integer?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, parsing, integer

I have a buffer like char array like this:

```
char buf[4];
buf[0] = 0x82;
buf[1] = 0x7e;
buf[2] = 0x01;
buf[3] = 0x00;
```

I would now like to read char two and three together as a 16Bit unsigned integer in big endian. How do I do this with C(++) standard tools?

Currently I would only know the manual solution:

```
int length = but[3];
length += but[2] << 8;
```

This would be easy for 16Bit integers but I need also to parse 32Bit integers which would make things a bit difficult. So is there a function from the standard lib which does this for me?

Bodo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store an int in a char array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522994/store-an-int-in-a-char-array)

Comment: This is the inverse operation from the proposed duplicate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ntohs` and `ntohl` (on a little endian system):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main(){
    char buf[4];
    buf[0] = 0x82;
    buf[1] = 0x7e;
    buf[2] = 0x01;
    buf[3] = 0x00;
    uint16_t raw16;
    uint32_t raw32;
    memcpy(&raw16, buf + 2, 2); 
    memcpy(&raw32, buf    , 4); 
    uint16_t len16 = ntohs(raw16);
    uint32_t len32 = ntohl(raw32);
    std::cout << len16 << std::endl;
    std::cout << len32 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can swap the bytes around and cast it to the appropriate type instead of shifting.

Comment: But what if `buf` is not "int aligned" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union :

```
union conv {
    char arr[4];
    short value16[2];
    int value32;
};

conv tmp;
tmp.arr[0] = buf[0];
tmp.arr[1] = buf[1];
tmp.arr[2] = buf[2];
tmp.arr[3] = buf[3];
```

Or memcpy :

```
memcpy(&length, buf, sizeof(length))
```

Comment: He does not ask for a conversion, we don't know if the system is big or little endian. If the system is big endian, the function needed is memcpy

Comment: the value of `value16[1]` needs to be 256, but with this I get 1 so you also need ntohs.

Comment: So you own a little endian system.

Answer (score -2):

[atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/). is more then likely the simpliest fix.

```
int iResult = atoi(buf);
```

Comment: `atoi()` will convert a string like "123" to the value 123.  It won't convert the characters 0x01 0x02 to 1x256 + 2 = 258, which is what the question is asking.